# Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() Error with inline arguments

Tags: sql, string

I have the following line of code in a c# project

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlText);
```

where sqlText is being loaded as...

```
'The date for the even is ''{EventDate}'' - with {EventID} - is not complete.'
```

... with the idea that this is just inserted into a varchar column in a sql table.

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'
```

I assume the problem here is that {EventDate} and {EventId} really need to be {0} and {1} and values would need to be supplied alongside? So this was just supposed to be executed as sql but at the moment, it won't do.

Comment: That does not look like SQL to me.

Comment: In an interpolated string C# will take the value of a variable of the same name if you prefix it with a `$` see - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: @Hogan of course you are right... i omitted the insert into column values part. this is the value being passed in.